# PHP Translate Binary to Text and back

Tags: javascript, binary

I want to translate binary to text and back in a form, I could not find any examples on google or something.

I wanted to make something like this 
http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp

I found this code while searching but I cant get it working :#

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function txt2bin()
    {
        url = 'http://services.webestools.com/txt2bin/txt2bin.js?str='+encodeURIComponent($('ftxt').value);
        var js_effets=document.createElement("script");
        js_effets.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        js_effets.setAttribute("src", url);
        document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.insertBefore(js_effets,document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]);
        $('frm').style.display='block';
    }
    function bin2txt()
    {
        url = 'http://services.webestools.com/txt2bin/bin2txt.js?str='+encodeURIComponent($('fbin').value);
        var js_effets=document.createElement("script");
        js_effets.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        js_effets.setAttribute("src", url);
        document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.insertBefore(js_effets,document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]);
        $('frm').style.display='block';
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want it in PHP?

PHP means you need a webserver that interprets your code. Your pasted snippet is in javascript, which is run by the browser and hence you don't need a server to just test it.

Anyway, doing it in javascript would actually be more efficient, if you want to create a tool like the one you linked.

2 functions in javascript to do the conversions:

```
function txt2bin(txt) {
    var pad = '00000000',
        bin = '',
        c = '';
    for(var i = 0, l = txt.length; i < l; i++) {
        c = txt.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
        bin += (pad + c).substr(c.length);
    }
    return bin;
}

function bin2txt(bin) {
    var split = bin.match(/.{8}/g),
        txt = '';
    for(var i = 0, l = split.length; i < l; i++) {
        txt += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(split[i], 2));
    }
    return txt;
}
```

test them here: http://jsfiddle.net/S3nB7/

`txt2bin` takes an ASCII encoded string and returns a binary representation of it.

`bin2txt` takes a string of 0 and 1 that represent the binary code of an ASCII encoded string and returns the ASCII string.

In **PHP** this would translate to:

```
<?php

function txt2bin($txt) {
    $bin = '';
    for($i = 0, $l = strlen($txt); $i < $l; $i++) {
        $bin .= sprintf('%08b', ord(substr($txt, $i, 1)));
    }
    return $bin;
}

function bin2txt($bin) {
    $split = str_split($bin, 8);
    $txt = '';
    for($i = 0, $l = count($split); $i < $l; $i++) {
        $txt .= chr(bindec($split[$i]));
    }
    return $txt;
}
```

test here: http://codepad.org/Y3sFJrR7

Comment: Well I wanted to do it in PHP because I know a bit of PHP and I know nothing in Javascript :p

Comment: I tried to get ur code working but I couldnt get it working :#
http://jsfiddle.net/bhEyf/